# How to get Geographical location from Browser in java

Tags: java, geolocation

I am working on the sample application and it need to put Geographical location in logs. Is there any API, or method that enable use to get the Geographical location from Browser in java.

Please advise if any.

Thanks

Comment: I just googled [this](http://www.browsergeolocation.com/) and I got scared, it showed my RL direction, too much precision.

Comment: location meaning latitude and longitude ?

Comment: If I want just country name, then?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can accomplish this. Both of these relay on the fact that you know the remote client IP address.

1. Have the Geo-location database downloaded locally and query this based on the IP addressed of the client received. [Geolite](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolite) is one such database and its updated regularly.
2. Subscribe to some online service like [GeoLoc](http://www.ipaddresslabs.com/) which return the location in an XML format based on the IP address passed.

Comment: If, I want just country name then?

Comment: Well, you will get the entire data (_that's how most of such services work_). Then you need to extract the country name from that.

Comment: My application in Java. Whenever user access my web based system, I need to get the Geolocation to log, I do not think it's appropriate using your approach.Am I right?

Comment: You will never get _Country_ from the user directly. It has to be derived based on the information (the IP address) you receive from the user. The only location related information you have is IP address and using this use some way (either of the two ways or similar other ways) to get the info you need.